# Targeting next Image that is inside a col class

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom, target

```
<div class="container bg-custom-blue">
  <h2 class="text-center pt-5 pb-4">The Responsive Gallery</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/waiter.jpg" alt="Waiter serving food">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/romantic.jpg" alt="A couple enjoying a romantic dinner at our restaurant">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/nibbles.jpg" alt="Tasty nibbles to share">
    </div>


    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/pasta-rucola-salad.jpg" alt="Fresh pasta with rucola">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/fish.jpg" alt="Fresh fillet of fish">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/fish.jpg" alt="One of our large selection of cakes we serve">
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/chill.jpg" alt="Friends enjoying wine">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/beef.jpg" alt="Argentinian beef fillet">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/nibbles.jpg" alt="Waiter serving food">
    </div>
```

I am trying to build an image gallery with arrows so you can press the next arrow and display next image (like all basic sliders). Since I just learned some basics of bootstrap I decided to use bootstrap for this project, however, I had to put every image in a separate col class (please notify me if this is not a good way). Since every image is in nested in another col class when I use `this.nextElementSibling` in the event listener I get `null` as a return. Is there any way that I can target the next image please?

Comment: No need to create this from scratch, bootstrap supports this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: Thanks @AdamH  but this is not exactly what I need. I am trying to build a gallery that when you click the image it is shown in larger size and the user can also navigate to the next and previous image. I am aware that there are plugins to do this however my intention is to practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this since you already using it for bootstrap

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find("img")
```

You can use Javascript as well as follow

```
this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.children[0];
```

Where children[0] means first child element

Comment: Thanks is there a way doing it using vanilla js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` and access your nodes via index.

**Small example**

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.row .col-12'); // all .col-12 notes inside .row
let currentIndex = 0; // current item index

// refresh icons and set border color
const refreshItems = () => {
  items.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.style.border = `1px solid ${index === currentIndex ? '#f00' : '#0f0'}`;
  });
}

// init
refreshItems();

// simple call by index
// items[5].style.border = '1px solid #0f0';

// Add click event to .prev button and increase current index 1
document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentIndex += 1;
  refreshItems();
});

// Add event to .prev button and decrease current index by 1
document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentIndex -= 1;
  refreshItems();
})
```

```html
<button class="next">next</button>
<button class="prev">prev</button>
<div class="container bg-custom-blue">
  <h2 class="text-center pt-5 pb-4">The Responsive Gallery</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/waiter.jpg" alt="Waiter serving food">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/romantic.jpg" alt="A couple enjoying a romantic dinner at our restaurant">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/nibbles.jpg" alt="Tasty nibbles to share">
    </div>


    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/pasta-rucola-salad.jpg" alt="Fresh pasta with rucola">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/fish.jpg" alt="Fresh fillet of fish">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/fish.jpg" alt="One of our large selection of cakes we serve">
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/chill.jpg" alt="Friends enjoying wine">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/beef.jpg" alt="Argentinian beef fillet">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 p-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="images/nibbles.jpg" alt="Waiter serving food">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lastly, add transforms, transitions, overflows, and index checks, and your slider is ready.